# SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] in Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

Integrating products and ratios of piecewise linear functions throws the error `Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with \ Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException]  SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]` after about 5 min and does not compute the integral. How to find the integral in closed form? It should almost be doable by hand because of the piecewise linear functions. `NIntegrate` works, although slowly.

```
Clear[v0, fv, fe0, fe, dfe, ne, w1, w2, h1, h2, qs, \
v0, qmax, vfoc0]
$Assumptions = 
  h2 > h1 > 0 && w2 > w1 > 0 &&  v0 > 0 && qmax > 0;
qs[v_, v0_] := 
  Piecewise[{{-qmax, v < -v0}, {qmax, 
     v > v0}, {v*qmax/v0, -v0 <= v <= v0}, {0, True}}];
fv[v_] := Piecewise[{{1/2, -1 <= v <= 1}, {0, True}}]
v0 = 0.8; qmax = 2.30; h1 = 0.01; h2 = 1.;
w1 = 2.0; w2 = 4.0; 
fe0[e_] := 
 Piecewise[{{h1, -w2 <= e < -w1 || 
     w1 < e <= w2}, {h2*(w1 - Abs[e])/w1 + 
     h1*(1 - (w1 - Abs[e])/w1), -w1 <= e <= w1}, {0, True}}]
ne = 2.06`;
fe[e_] := fe0[e]/ne;
dfe[e_] := 
 Piecewise[{{0, -w2 <= e < -w1 || w1 < e <= w2}, {(h2 - h1)/w1, -w1 <=
      e <= 0}, {-(h2 - h1)/w1, 0 <= e <= w1}, {0, True}}]
vfoc0 = (-q*
      Integrate[v*fe[q + \[Epsilon] - qs[v, v0]]*fv[v], {v, -1, 1}]*
      Integrate[fv[v]*dfe[q + \[Epsilon] - qs[v, v0]], {v, -1, 1}] + 
     Integrate[
       fe[q + \[Epsilon] - qs[v, v0]]*fv[v], {v, -1, 
        1}]*(Integrate[
         v*fe[q + \[Epsilon] - qs[v, v0]]*fv[v], {v, -1, 1}] + 
        q*Integrate[
          v*fv[v]*dfe[q + \[Epsilon] - qs[v, v0]], {v, -1, 1}]))/
   Integrate[fe[q + \[Epsilon] - qs[v, v0]]*fv[v], {v, -1, 1}]^2;
Integrate[
 fe[\[Epsilon]]*vfoc0, {\[Epsilon], -w2, 
  w2}](*Takes >5 min. Does not integrate with breakpoints -w1,0,w1. \
Does not integrate with vfoc0/.{z->q+\[Epsilon]}, \
SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"].*)
```

Same error using rationals for the parameters instead of decimals. Same with `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`.

Mathematica 11.3 on Ubuntu 18.04, Dell Latitude E7470. Sometimes also Mathematica freezes with the system message "Mathematica has stopped responding. Force quit. Wait."

Using `PiecewiseExpand`, same error. The modified code using rationals, `Set` and `PiecewiseExpand` is

```
Clear[v0, fv, fe0, fe, dfe, dfe0, ne, w1, w2, h1, h2, qs, v0, qmax, \
vfoc0]
$Assumptions = h2 > h1 > 0 && w2 > w1 > 0 && v0 > 0 && qmax > 0;
qs = Piecewise[{{-qmax, v < -v0}, {qmax, 
     v > v0}, {v*qmax/v0, -v0 <= v <= v0}, {0, True}}];
fv = Piecewise[{{1/2, -1 <= v <= 1}, {0, True}}];
v0 = 8/10; qmax = 23/10; h1 = 1/100; h2 = 1;
w1 = 2; w2 = 4; h1v = 1; h2v = 2;
fe0 = PiecewiseExpand[
   Piecewise[{{h1, -w2 <= q + \[Epsilon] - qs < -w1 || 
       w1 < q + \[Epsilon] - qs <= 
        w2}, {h2*(w1 - Abs[q + \[Epsilon] - qs])/w1 + 
       h1*(1 - (w1 - Abs[q + \[Epsilon] - qs])/w1), -w1 <= 
       q + \[Epsilon] - qs <= w1}, {0, True}}], 
   h2 > h1 > 0 && w2 > w1 > 0 && v0 > 0 && qmax > 0, Reals];
ne = 206/100;
fe = fe0/ne;
dfe0 = PiecewiseExpand[
   Piecewise[{{0, -w2 <= q + \[Epsilon] - qs < -w1 || 
       w1 < q + \[Epsilon] - qs <= w2}, {(h2 - h1)/w1, -w1 <= 
       q + \[Epsilon] - qs <= 0}, {-(h2 - h1)/w1, 
      0 < q + \[Epsilon] - qs <= w1}, {0, True}}], 
   h2 > h1 > 0 && w2 > w1 > 0 && v0 > 0 && qmax > 0, Reals];
dfe = dfe0/ne;
vfoc0 = (-q*Integrate[v*fe*fv, {v, -1, 1}]*
      Integrate[fv*dfe, {v, -1, 1}] + 
     Integrate[
       fe*fv, {v, -1, 1}]*(Integrate[v*fe*fv, {v, -1, 1}] + 
        q*Integrate[v*fv*dfe, {v, -1, 1}]))/
   Integrate[fe*fv, {v, -1, 1}]^2;
Integrate[
 PiecewiseExpand[fe*vfoc0, 
  h2 > h1 > 0 && w2 > w1 > 0 && v0 > 0 && qmax > 0, 
  Reals], {\[Epsilon], -w2, w2}]
```

Adding `Simplify@` in front of `PiecewiseExpand` everywhere creates the warnings `Power: Infinite expression 1/0^2 encountered` and `Infinity: Indeterminate expression 0ComplexInfinity encountered`, same `SystemException` at the end.

Comment: Does it behave differently if you use rationals instead of decimal values?

Comment: On Mathematica 12.1 (Linux), the code block in the question crashed the kernel after about 15 minutes with an apparent peak memory usage of around 10GB.

Comment: Have you tried perhaps heavy use of Simplify and PiecewiseExpand on your expressions? vfoc0 is a pretty heavily nested combination of Piecewise function. That may be why the system chokes following the maze of branches. You may also consider using rationals for symbolic integration, and `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` to avoid unnecessary recomputations.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Same behaviour with rationals. Same with `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`. Will investigate `Simplify` and `PiecewiseExpand` - the latter I have not used before.

Comment: @MarcoB I tried adding Simplify and PiecewiseExpand (new code copied to the edited question). Same error.